# Calculate number of leaves taken by Employee in a month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I calculate number of leaves taken by Employee in a month in SQL Server?

```
Empid   Leaveid   Fromdate    Todate      No of days
100     L1        2008-05-10  2008-05-13  3
100     L2        2008-05-20  2008-05-21  1
100     L3        2008-05-25  2008-06-05  12
100     L4        2009-01-20  2009-01-22  2
100     L5        2009-02-14  2009-02-20  6
100     L6        2009-02-28  2009-02-28  1
```

Comment: Post up the rest if your homework/exam/corsework and we can do that ass well for you :)

Comment: Use aggregate function (SUM) and GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT Empid, SUM([No of Days]) AS Days
FROM leavetable
GROUP BY Empid
```

Read more here [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) and here [SUM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx).

This would give you:

```
Empid Days
100   25
```

Or if you mean count the amount of times an employee has been off use `Count`.

```
SELECT Empid, Count(Leaveid) AS LeaveTotal 
FROM leavetable
GROUP BY Empid
```

Read more here [COUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx).

This would give you:

```
Empid LeaveTotal
100   6
```

Comment: I think the user want leaves in one month, and you ae giving him total leaves or total count of leaves. Which is not the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #EmpLeave (EmpId INT, LeaveID VARCHAR(5), FromDate Date, Todate Date, NoOfDays INT)
INSERT INTO #EmpLeave VALUES
(100,     'L1',        '2008-05-10',  '2008-05-13',  4),
(100,     'L2',        '2008-05-20',  '2008-05-21',  2),
(100,     'L3',        '2008-05-25',  '2008-06-05',  12),
(100,     'L4',        '2009-01-20',  '2009-01-22',  3),
(100,     'L5',        '2009-02-14',  '2009-02-20',  7),
(100,     'L6',        '2009-02-28',  '2009-02-28',  1)


;With CTE_leave AS (
select * from #EmpLeave where Month(FromDate) <> Month(ToDate) )


SELECT a.EMPID,DATENAME(MONTH,FromDate ) Month ,SUM(a.LeaveCount) LeaveTaken
FROM 
(

SELECT C.EMPID,C.LeaveID, C.FromDate, DATEDIFF(DD,C.FromDate,EOMonth(FromDate) ) + 1 LeaveCount
FROM CTE_Leave C
UNION
SELECT C.EMPID, C.LeaveID, DATEADD(DD,1, EOMonth(FromDate)) fromDate, DATEDIFF(DD,DATEADD(DD,1, EOMonth(FromDate)), C.ToDate ) + 1 LeaveCount
FROM CTE_Leave C
UNION
SELECT EMPID, LeaveID, FromDate,  DATEDIFF(DD, FromDate, Todate) + 1 LeaveCount FROM #EmpLeave where Month(FromDate) = Month(ToDate) 
) a
group by a.EMPID,  DATENAME(MONTH,FromDate )
```

@Anchalose find above possible solution. Let us know solves your query.
Please do post schema details along with the desired result also while posting your query, it will help us understand the problem better.

@Matt, please refrain from using cuss words and try to post the solution as per the requirement.